# Calculating coastal distances using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance, ocean

I'm trying to work up some historical transport cost maps, across multiple modes (road/rail/sea/river). I have a polygon shapefile of the coast itself, and point data on the cities of interest (some of which are coastal). I'm using QGIS if that is relevant.

Re: coastal routes in particular, I'm not sure what the best way is to generate a coastal distance measure between two port cities A and B.

One approximation is the length of coast between A and B, which I think will be an overestimate given the ruggedness of the coastline. The two ideas I had to improve on this were:

1. I could use a buffer and then take some kind of smoothed median line parallel to the coastline.
2. I could simplify the geometries of the coastline to wash out coastal details, and simply use the length of that. (Possibly I could offset the coast by N km and simplify that.)

Does this make sense?

Comment: Both sound reasonable to me. Potential problem, if there is, such operation may push any part of line into the waters, e.g. bay area or highly rugged areas. Then third option would be (1) turn coastline line feature into polygon, then (2) create a negative buffer... This will ensure the new line stays on land.

Comment: You might want to incorporate elevation into your estimate. When traveling by land, the shortest route may cross unrealistically steep slopes.

Comment: What happens when you try each of your ideas?  Does either result seem like an improvement to you?